# Decrease value of a field using Spring JDBC template

Tags: database, spring, db2, spring-jdbc

I am trying to decrease the value of a field in DB2 Table using Spring JDBC template.Below is my code

```
String sql= "UPDATE XYZ SET CURR_COUNT = CURR_COUNT-1 WHERE COMPANY_CODE =?";
int rowsUpdated = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {compCode});
```

This gives me error `"**PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar**"`
If I am not wrong the error is because of this `**"CURR_COUNT = CURR_COUNT-1"**` as program dont have value of CURR_COUNT. Can anybody suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: And what is the Problem with your code?

Comment: @Jens edited the question

Comment: Add the compltet stacktrace

Answer (score -2):

You could take value from database via `SELECT` to variable (int or long), decrement it in java, and then save new value in `UPDATE` query.